# TeXShop: (R) gets converted into circled R

Tags: texshop

I am having a bit of trouble finding a solution. When I type `(R)` TeXShop changes it into circled R. I changed the setting in Language & Text, disabling "Use the symbol and text substitution." However, TeXShop still converts my `(R)` into circled R. I was not able to find an option in TeXShop. I feel like it is somewhere I just can't find it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) is the preferred way here to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Which OS and which version of TeXshop are you using? I cannot replicate your problem on Mac OS 10.8.3 and TeXShop 2.47.

Comment: I too do _not_ see the behavior with TeXShop 2.47 that you are seeing.  But, if you changed a setting, I think you may need to restart TeXShop for that setting to take effect. If that does not resolve your issue, please provide details as requested by @Jubobs.

Comment: Try the same text in a TextEdit window. If you still get the substitution it's an OS setting, not TeXShop.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the answers. Yes, I am new to here. I am happy to hear Jubobs suggestion. 

I am using OS X 10.8.3 and TeXShop 3.10. I tried with TextEdit, but it didn't covert (R) to circled R. It is still converting on TeXShop.

Comment: I went back to Text tab on Language and Text setting. I just checked and unchecked the "Use symbol and text substitution" option, and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 7):

Try disabling OS X system-wide Text Expansion in System Preferences -> Language & Text ([video](http://macdailynews.com/2012/08/10/how-to-use-os-x-mountain-lions-built-in-substitution-text-expansion-feature-with-video/)). The symbol (R) is substituted by default.

Comment: ...or use another editor (Emacs+AUCTeX (!)).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Clearly the best option :P  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides.