# Override Registered Symbol

Tags: symbols

I need to include '(r)' in my document, but it defaults to the registered trademark sign, ® .

How can I override this?

Comment: Most likely this is done by your editor, not after compiling, right? If so, which editor are you using?

Comment: Yes, its being changed by the editor. I'm using TeXShop.

Comment: See [TeXShop (R) into circled R](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107308/5764). Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, this fixed it.